# json_decode big number

Tags: php, json, biginteger

I have problem when decode json string

My PHP version is 5.4.4-7 and my OS is Debian amd64.

JSON string is:

```
{"status":"success","account":{"buy_title":"KGP ID","birthday":0,"sex":0,"phone_number":"","avatar":"http:\/\/\/default\/avatar_default.png","password":"","virtual_id":"1348718752795","point":0,"quota":2,"level":1,"remain":3413838437,"token":"9702040ea11e2b87d005056b771ea","email":"ngokhat@gmail.com","buy_link":"http:\/\/id.kgp.vn","fullname":""}}*
```

I want to get remain = 3413838437 and virtual_id = 1348718752795
but when I get

```
$result = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

`$result['account']['remain']` it return 2147483647 and `$result['account']['virtual_id]` return 2147483647 too. I don't know why is that I've searched and found https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/php-json/c-zOACBlCPs but link patch are died

How to fix that?

Comment: What version of PHP?  `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is only available in PHP 5.4.

Comment: Are you running on 32bit OS, 32bit PHP?

Comment: @sberry, That won't matter if he's trying to get the integer as a string.

Comment: @Brad, I only ask because mine decodes just fine without the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` flag.  PHP 5.3

Comment: @sepdau: What is the output of `php -r 'echo PHP_INT_SIZE;'`

Comment: @Brad, on versions earlier that 5.4 it will raise an exception because of 4 arguments when 3 are expected.

Comment: @Brad my php version is 5.4.4-7

Comment: Please add your php version at your question on 5.3 this works fine

Answer (score 3):

> ini_set('precision', 20);

or in php.ini search precision and put precision in 20.

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine for me:

```
php > print_r(json_decode($json, true));
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [account] => Array
        (
            [buy_title] => KGP ID
            [birthday] => 0
            [sex] => 0
            [phone_number] => 
            [avatar] => http:///default/avatar_default.png
            [password] => 
            [virtual_id] => 1348718752795
            [point] => 0
            [quota] => 2
            [level] => 1
            [remain] => 3413838437
            [token] => 9702040ea11e2b87d005056b771ea
            [email] => ngokhat@gmail.com
            [buy_link] => http://id.kgp.vn
            [fullname] => 
        )

)
```

This is on 64 bit PHP, which you are running also since your PHP_INT_SIZE is 8.

Answer (score 0):

This was because in database I set this field is INT. I've just modified to bigint and it work correctly!